# Not able to use LWC on VF page which is used for login flow using VF Pages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, visual-workflow

I have a login flow which is calling a VF page. I am calling a Lightning app from vf page which calls LWC. When i preview the VF page its working fine. But when i use it in a flow its not working. Is lightning out not supported in Login flows?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. would you mind adding your code or any error you see in dev console

Comment: Thanks but i figured it out.

Comment: Sourav, can you post your solution please? I'm facing the same issue.