# lightning is not allowed in VF login flow

Tags: visualforce, lightning, loginflow

I try to use lwc in VF page and use the VF page in a login flow.
User **can view** the page after login. So I think the issue is not related to permission. But during login flow, the page will not display and I find below error in console.
[image: error message in console]

I have checked below posts. But there is no solution or official document about why lightning (including lwc and flow in lightning runtime) is not allowed in VF login flow. I think that may be related to user authorization status during login flow. Any idea about this issue?

1. [lightning out not working with login flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263587/lightning-out-not-working-with-login-flow)
2. [Not able to use LWC on VF page which is used for login flow using VF Pages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305829/not-able-to-use-lwc-on-vf-page-which-is-used-for-login-flow-using-vf-pages)

lightning application code:

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp" >
  <aura:dependency resource="LWCname" />
</aura:application>
```

VF page code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />    
    <div id="LightningComponentid" />    
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:AppName", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:LWCname",
          { 
          },
          "LightningComponentid",
          function(cmp) {
             console.log('LWC Componenet added in VF page');
          });
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes, that error specifically has to do with an attempted 302 (redirect) to the login page. Have you tried just putting the component into the flow itself?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your advise. It is available to use lwc in flow with login flow. But we have forbiden standard page in this site. So user can't access the flow and we need to display the lwc in vf login flow. According to my research, it is not available to use lwc in vf page within login flow.